# Non-profit Starter Pack -> Contact field question

Tags: contact, fields, nonprofit-starter-pack

In the Non-profit Starter/Success Pack version, Contacts has a checkbox field called Private. What is the semantic meaning of this field?

Related to this question, I have searched for a listing of the default fields and their semantic meanings, and come up empty.

Comment: I'm not sure on that version, but if it has the same meaning as the Private checkbox on an attachment, it would mean that only the person who added/owns the record can see it (as well as any admins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the help text on the field in Setup:

> Excludes this Contact from One to One or Bucket account processing

It's a very rare that you'll need to use the Private checkbox.

Your best resource for NPSP support is the Salesforce Foundation's [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com).

You can login with your Salesforce ID and gain access to Chatter groups covering many aspects of the NPSP. Foundation staff, consultants and non-profit organizations are all participants in the groups.